# How to define a custom locale with my own calendar settings?

Tags: linux, locale

I want to define a custom locale with my own calendar settings. In this locale, we set a specified year as the first year. For example, if I define a en_UNIX.UTF-8, I'd like to set AD 1970 as year 1, and AD 1970 as year 2.

Is there any way to do this in Linux/BSD? I looked into system's locale files and found they only defined the first day of week, currency and so on except the first year of calendar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of the gregorian calendar is hard-coded in glibc: https://github.com/rbdixon/glibc/blob/master/time/offtime.c#L58

So anything that uses the C library ("system") routines - `gmtime_r`, `localtime_r` and so on - to convert between seconds-since-the-epoch and broken-down-date format, will stick to the "standard" calendar (365 days in a year, Gregorian leap-year formula, 7 days per week...).

For code you write yourself, you could use the [ICU Project](http://site.icu-project.org/)'s libraries and provide your own non-Gergorian calendar specification in the [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec) XML [format](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html).

I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that.

Comment: I found many GNOME applications are depends on libicu, is there anyway to set non-Gergorian calender for these applications?

Comment: @LingfengXiong Not usefully, because libicu is probably mostly used to deal with unicode character set and font handling for internationalisation, not for date handling. It _may_ be used for that, but there's not much of a way to find out: you'd need to find/create a suitable calendar definition, make sure it's installed/available, set your timezone to that one, and see if it makes a difference. And even if it does, it might not in all places in the code, and if it doesn't, perhaps that build simply can't or won't load it without a recompile, but would.

Comment: thanks for your kindly help :-) Does Mac OS X (GUI applications) and FreeBSD handle this kind of things in the same way?

Comment: The situation on FreeBSD is essentially identical to Linux; I have absolutely no idea what support MacOS provides for time/date handling beyond basic Unix routines, and to what extent you can expect it to be used.